# Call function when stderr is written to in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, assert, stderr

Is there a way to execute a callback function, or otherwise call a predefined function whenever data is written to a standard stream such as `stderr` or `stdout`? Ideally, this could be used to allow an application to output as normal with `printf` in the case of `stdout` or `fprintf` for other `FILE` streams, and conditionally perform additional tasks such as assert dependent on current settings. This could have the benefit of automatically triggering this error handling code when other libraries output to the stream.

I know that output to `stderr` and `stdout` can be redirected to other `FILE` handles using `std::freopen`. Is it practical to implement an alternate `FILE` stream which provides this behavior, or would that require re-implementing a great deal of standard library functions?

Standards-compliant C++ suggestions (including C++11) would be preferred, although I would be open to Windows only solutions if necessary.

---

I've since had an attempt at implementing a streambuffer as suggested by [doomster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429990/1995485), with a little help from [Filtering Streambufs](http://gabisoft.free.fr/articles/fltrsbf1.html) by James Kanze. Unless any other suggestions come up, it seems like this is the closest you can get to the original suggestion. It won't intercept C-style output, which I suspect that is either impossible or at impractical, but it otherwise provides all the functionality I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the streambuffer in order to intercept any output to those streams, see the rdbuf() function. I think you only need to implement the overflow() function in the streambuffer class.